# Python - Query column values against function in package - works on single results, but not across column

Tags: python, pandas, loops, for-loop, package

I have a Python package installed that displays Google geography info from a search term. I cannot apply the function across all the rows in my data. I can confirm that it works for a single result:

[image]

But how can I apply this across every row in the 7th column?

I understand I need a for loop:

[image]

But how do I apply my function from the package to each row?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a **[mcve]**. In particular, please do not post images, but feel free to include extracts of your data via `df.head().to_dict()`. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pd.Series.map` is one way to vectorise your algorithm:

```
data2['geocode_result'] = data2['ghana_city'].map(gmaps.geocode)
```

This is still not vectorised as `gmaps.geocode()` will be applied to every element in the series. But, similar to [@ScratchNPurr's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49115196/9209546), you should see a improvement.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function which is faster:

```
data2['geocode_result'] = data2['ghana_city'].apply(lambda x: gmaps.geocode(x))
```

Result will be JSON strings in the `geocode_result` column, so you may have to define some custom function to extract the information you want from the strings. At least apply will be a step towards the right direction.